# Voltage follower with shift

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, level-shifting

I am trying to figure out a simple application/ circuit that would allow me to shift the voltage a little bit. Lets say we have an input voltage of range from 0 to 1 V. I need an output voltage of 0.2 to 1.2 V. This is just an example but I am looking for a generic solution. There is no negative voltage available in the circuit.

Comment: @le_top: No, that won't work at all. Draw it out on paper and maybe you'll see why.

Comment: Ok, maybe I wrote it out wrong - so I'll delete my comment as your drawing is what I meant to describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic 4-resistor difference amplifier will do what you want:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFXox9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This circuit keeps the difference between Vout and Vref equal to the difference between V+ and V-, effectively adding Vref to V+ if V- is grounded.

The opamp tries to keep its two input terminals at the same potential using negative feedback:

$$ \frac{V_{out} + V_-}{2} = \frac{V_{ref} + V_+}{2}$$

Multiply both sides by 2 and rearrange the terms to get:

$$V_{out} - V_{ref} = V_+ - V_-$$

[image: simulation result]

Comment: Yes, I messed up the terminals. I think its the simplest way, thanks.